# Read encrypted PDF as a stream in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to read an encrypted PDF (encrypted using my own key) as a stream in iOS. The idea being that I can decrypt the document in chunks and pass it to the renderer as opposed to decrypting the entire document, which is not an option since:

1. Decrypting the entire document will be slower
2. If the doc is large, then I can't fit the entire decrypted content in memory
3. Writing to disk is not an option since I don't want decrypted copies of the doc lying around anywhere on the disk even for a short interval.

I know that we can do this with UIWebView using asynchronous URL requests; but UIWebView is too slow for me; esp with large PDFs.

Can someone suggest any way to do this with QLPreviewController (QuickLaunch framework) or the CGPDFDocument?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider)` where `provider` is created with `CGDataProviderCreateDirect()` or `CGDataProviderCreateSequential()` ?

I have not used these functions, but they seem to do what you need.

But it could be that Core Graphics will cache the entire PDF document either in memory or in a temporary file.

The reason is that PDF is a structured format containing many objects (referencing other objects in the document) and a table of contents. The table of contents is often at the end of the document and must be read before any objects can be read.

Comment: I can get around the TOC being at the end by linearizing all my PDFs (ie. moving the TOC to the beginning of the file).

Comment: Yes, my point was only that you have no control over what Core Graphics does. Even for the last page it needs the TOC and perhaps resources from the start of the file, so there are legitimate reasons for caching. Just try it and check the memory consumption with Instruments.